# Looses focus after write one word in input when use UseSelctor. why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, deployment, rtk-query

Here is parent and child. i use UseSelector to get state and pass it child component. But when i write something in input it looses the focus. why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaeH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdM0b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMS93.png)
here is some pics fo that

Comment: Links to images of code are not very useful here. Images can be difficult to read, are not accessible, and not copy/pasteable. Please [edit] to include the relevant code as properly formatted and readable code snippets. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the `Item` component inside another component, it's recreated each time the parent component renders/rerenders. When a new "instance" of `Item` mounts, its ***entire*** sub-ReactTree is also mounted, including the inputs that `InvoiceDetails` rendered. The inputs lose focus when they are unmounted.

Move the `Item` declaration outside the `Invoice` component.

Comment: Awesome, I have been doing this for the last 6-7 hours. How to learn all this. It's been 2 months learning Reactjs.